# Error after inputting frmttable stata table

Tags: tables, input

I am using the Stata user written command frmttable to create journal-like tables and to write them to LaTex. When I use the command \input{... .tex} the table is displayed like I want it, but LaTex stops compilation afterwards. Also, right before the table it mentions []article in the final pdf document.
My code looks as following:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
...
\begin{flushleft}
\input{Table.tex}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

I get the error 'Can be used only in the preamble ... \documentclass'. Is there a package I still need to install?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is inside `Table.tex`? From the error message I suspect there is `\documentclass` statement in `Table.tex` which is wrong in this case

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: This is the document statement in the Table.tex file:                     \documentclass[]{article}\pagestyle{empty}\begin{document}

Comment: @Elisa: You **can't** have those statements in the `Table.tex` file

Comment: @Christian: Thanks for your suggestion! When I erase the document statement, the '[]article' indeed disappears and deleting the \begin{document} ... \end{document} solves for the problem of stopping the compilation.

Comment: @Elisa: Apparently, there are other errors in the mentioned file

Comment: @Christian: yes indeed, there were! I updated my previous post.

Comment: @Elisa: Shall we close this question then?

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment yet (and although I'm very late to the party), let me add one thing as an answer: Stata's `frmttable` knows the option `fragment`, which will strip the LaTeX output off the `\begin{document}` and the `\begin{table}` parts, having the code start with `\begin{tabular}` (or, before the latter, `\begin{center}` if you don't add the option `nocenter` as well). This way you won't have to eliminate the respective lines manually.